# Айфон и ssh и shell

Tags: iphone, shell, ssh

Можно ли как-то закидывать музыку через консоль ubuntu ,по ssh прямо в стандартный плеер айфона .
Если ещё более подробнее уточнить вопрос то , я должен зайти с убунту по ssh к себе на айфон и найти папку где храниться Музыка которая поступает на встроенный плеер айфона и уже туда перемещать аудио файлы,

И желательно по вай-фай а через интернет или по локальной сети это не так важно.

например командой `mv *.mp3`

Comment: А что такое - консоль Ubuntu? Уточните.

Comment: Нельзя. Нужен iTunes

Comment: @0xdb консоль стандартная unix , он же терминал то что и в маке есть

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну просто на ubuntu , нету Айтюнс

Comment: Я знаю. Приходиться изворачиваться виртуалкой с виндой

Comment: @AlexeyTen вы имеете в виду виртуал бокс или wine ?

Comment: У меня Virtualbox, wine не пробовал

Comment: @AlexeyTen wine выдаёт ошибку и не запускает Айтюнс так что и не стоит

Comment: @coffeehoock через терминал на iPhone по ssh с пк под Ubuntu - правильно понял?

Comment: @0xdb да например командой mv *.mp3

Comment: @0xdb если ещё более подробнее уточнить вопрос то , я должен зайти с убунту по ssh к себе на айфон и найти папку где храниться Музыка которая поступает на встроенный плеер айфона и уже туда перемещать аудио файлы

Comment: И желательно по вай-фай а через интернет или по локальной сети это не так важно

Comment: Чувак `Mac` купи :D или на `Google Drive` загрузи и на айфоне скачай. Не забудь установить программу `Documents by Readdle` в неё будет очень удобно скачивать.

Comment: @EugenEray Я же не ищу легких путей ))) Спасибо попробую , а мак по любому нужно брать

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/659945/edit) и дополните ваш вопрос на основе комментариев.

Comment: @coffeehoock, а на iPhone/iPad вообще возможно зайти по ssh? Или по любому другому протоколу удалённого доступа? А то я считал, что нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy не факт я это и пытаюсь выяснить , покорней мере я видел приложения в апстор которые помогают подключиться , но они платные и я их не юзал , но есть приложения которые я побывал и они через браузер закачивают файлы на айфон , но мой вопрос как обойтись без приложений

Comment: @coffeehoock, в таком случае я бы отдельно спрашивал про удалённое управление...

Comment: яблоки шифруют медиа файлы - удаленных протоколов передачи данных не поддерживают (ftp/ssh/telnet etc).  попробуйте Banshee/Rythmbox/Amaroc/Climenteen -  это стандартные GNU/Linux медия плееры поддерживающе яблоки.